# Getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to scrape a site using BeautifulSoup4 and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a URL using BS4 and Python. I'm trying to parse the data of a particular table on the page into a Pandas dataframe. What I am experiencing however is that the website is throwing up a 403 error - which I'm presuming is because I"m not declaring a specific user agent and there is some kind of security on the site that prevents me from scraping this data.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.example.com/example"
data = requests.get(URL).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find_all('table')
table = soup.find('table', class_="table table-hover")

df_pandas = pd.read_html(URL, attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover'},  flavor='bs4', thousands =',')

df_pandas[0].head()
```

So the error I am experiencing in the terminal is this:

`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

But I am not calling urllib at any point within the code, so I'm presuming there's something about calling df_pandas[0].head() that is making a urllib request to the site, and because this is without any kind of user agent, it gets blocked.

My question is, how do I modify this code in order to ensure my request declares a user agent and doesn't get blocked?

Comment: I would think that the error comes from either `read_html` or `requests.get`. Why do you think it comes from `df_pandas[0].head()`? Is that what the traceback says?

Comment: So I'm pretty sure it doesn't come from request.get because if I just go print(data) I get no error. I hadn't considered read_html - so possibly yes, this is where it comes from. But how would I amend read_html to add a user agent to verify whether this is the issue?

Comment: If the data you get from `requests.get` works you can pass that data (or maybe even the bs4 version of it) to read_html as it accepts HTML other than a URL

Comment: Troubling shooting method - Have you tried to connect to only `https://www.example.com`?  eg. `data = requests.get(URL)  print(data.status_code)'.  Do you get a 403?

Comment: The error is most likely from `pd.read_html`, but why are you using `read_html(URL,....` instead of `read_html(data,...`? [You can also try `df_pandas = pd.read_html(str(table))`] But most importantly, you should always check response status like Lifeiscomplex suggested. [ Btw, if you have a difficult time figuring out the user agents, I suggest trying [`HTMLSession`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) or [`cloudscraper`](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/#:~:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20use%20cloudscraper%20is%20by%20calling) instead of `requests` ]

Answer (score 0):

you can add a User-Agent to your header:

for example:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

data = requests.get(URL, headers=headers).text
```

You can produce many user-agent and replace them. There are many sites that generate user-agents.

[like this](https://iplogger.org/useragents/)